# Problemas con zoom en navegadores

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo un inconveniente por decirlo al momento de realizar un zoom a 90% en el explorador de google chrome la pagina por decirlo asi pierde los estilos aplicados por los css , aqui adjunto un ejemplo de lo que sucede.

Web con zoom al 100%

[image: Web al 100%]

Web con zoom al 90%

[image: Web con zoom al 90%]

Adjunto la porción de código del bloque que contiene esa información en los exploradores se visualiza sin problema alguna cuando esta al 100% y empieza a crecer , el problema radica cuando el usuario desea o realiza un disminución del zoom.

```
<div class="container_box">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon_box">
                <img class="fa" align="center" src="../../img/web/search.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h3>Políticas</h3><br>
                <p align="justify">Es una organización innovadora que garantiza a sus clientes de Ecuador y el mundo la calidad e inocuidad de su producto, con personal competente</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon_box">
                <img class="fa" align="center" src="../../img/web/mision.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h3>Misión</h3><br>
                <p align="justify">Satisfacer las necesidades y expectativas de sus clientes actuales y potenciales, suministrándoles productos de calidad, a fin de lograr el fortalecimiento y liderazgo institucional.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon_box">
                <img class="fa" align="center" src="../../img/web/vision.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content_box">
                <h3>Visión</h3><br>
                <p align="justify">Consolidarse como una empresa líder dentro del mercado de procesamiento de productos acuícolas, brindando un servicio de calidad que se proyecte a través del tiempo, con el mejor talento humano y una organización ágil.</p>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

A continuación el código del css con el cual implemento la vista que visualiza el usuario al 100%

```
.container_body{
        position: relative;
        width: 350px;
        height: 1140px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        margin-bottom: 50px;            
  }

  .container_box{
        position: relative;
        width: 350px;
        height: 1080px;
        margin: 40px auto;

  }

  .container_box .box{
        position: relative;
        width: calc(350px - 30px);
        height: calc(380px - 30px);   
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;           
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 20px;
  }

  .container_box .box .icon_box{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;     
        background: #f00;
        transition: 0.5s;
        z-index: 1;
  }

  .container_box .box:hover .icon_box{
        top: 20px;
        left: calc(50% - 40px);
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .container_box .box .icon_box .fa{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-45%,-55%);
        font-size: 80px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: #fff; 
  }

  .container_box .box:hover .icon_box .fa{  
        font-size: 40px;  
  }

  .container_box .box .content_box{
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: 0.5s;
        opacity: 1;
  }

  .container_box .box:hover .content_box {
        top: 100px;
        opacity: 1;
  }

  .container_box .box .content_box h3{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 24px;
  }

  .container_box .box .content_box p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.0em;
  }

  .container_box .box:nth-child(1) .icon_box{
        background: #0C1254;
  }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Llevas un buen tiempo en el sitio, ya deberías saber que una imagen no aporta mucho, con ella no podemos reproducir el problema que tienes, por favor añade tu código siguiendo las recomendaciones sobre [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Carrobe90, ¿por favor podrías compartir el código html de la imagen mostrada para poder ayudarte?

Answer (score 0):

El problema podria estar en los Media Queries, recuerda que al hacer zoom en el navegador, el viewport se ajusta, probablemente, este reconociendo un media querie mas chico y por esa razón te elimina los estilos.
Me sucedió lo mismo una vez que maneje varios hojas de estilos por tamaños de navegador.

El detalle seria saber como estas mandando a llamar tu hoja de estilos